# Loading Local Environmental Variables in Config Initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I was setting up Segment.com's analytics_ruby.rb file in my config/initaializers folder and couldn't seem to get environmental variables I had placed in my .env to load. My assumption was that "heroku open" would automatically load these values--not the case.

```
Analytics = Segment::Analytics.new({
  write_key: ENV['SEGMENT_KEY'],
  on_error: Proc.new { |status, msg| print msg }
})
```

As a result I was getting this error:

> /gems/analytics-ruby-2.0.13/lib/segment/analytics/client.rb:319:in
>   `check_write_key!': Write key must be initialized (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 0):

Solution, add the dotenv-rails gem to your :development and :test group:

```
  # Load Local Environmental Variables .ENV
  gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv